# Smooth Scroll generating :active attribute on target div

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I am using a jQuery scroller to scroll to a certain element on the page. In this case it is the Navbar. However I am experiencing a strange issue. After clicking the button to scroll to the element the resulting element generates a `focus` attribute as so.

[image]

This disappears and reappears when I click and unclick the element. It only occurs after I click the button to scroll to this location. I have tried target the div with a focus tag and declaring it `.navbar:focus { box-shadow: none;}` but it doesn't work

I am using the following to generate the scroll effect and am targeting the element by 
`<a href="#navigationtop" class="anchorLink">`

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var scrollElement = 'html, body';
 $('html, body').each(function () {
  var initScrollTop = $(this).attr('scrollTop');
  $(this).attr('scrollTop', initScrollTop + 1);
   if ($(this).attr('scrollTop') == initScrollTop + 1) {
  scrollElement = this.nodeName.toLowerCase();
  $(this).attr('scrollTop', initScrollTop);
  return false;
    }    
   });

  // Smooth scrolling for internal links
  $("a[href^='#']").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

var $this = $(this),
target = this.hash,
$target = $(target);

$(scrollElement).stop().animate({
  'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
}, 500, 'swing', function() {
  window.location.hash = target;
});

});

});
```

Comment: What do you mean 'the resulting element generates a focus attribute'?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'focus' attribute for an html element..  and how an element generate an attribute for itself?  doesn't make sense.

Comment: thats the best way I could describe it.....when I click it, it adds I presume, a box shadow to it but only after the button to scroll has been presesed

Comment: You should first try to inspect the element in something like Chrome Developer tools(F12) and look at the styles that are applied to the element after the scroll button has been clicked.. you probably have something in you css style..  like a:active {box-shadow: bla bla).. Would need to see some of your html and css to be able to find our more about what is happening here.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your master.css file,  you have a style definition:

```
.navbar-default {background: #F7F7F7!important; 
border: none!important;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif!important;
}
```

Try this:

Add `outline: none;` to this style definition.

Comment: no luck Bryan. That targets my shadow that I wish to keep. The grey #888. I need the blue on the navigation that appears after you click the slider to disapear

Comment: hmm. Im not exactly sure what you are referring to..  what browser are you using?

Comment: I edited my answer.  I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're referring to, but give it a try..  :)

Comment: didn't do the trick exaclty how I wanted it but it worked to a degree so will accept the answer. Kinda ended up doing a hack to fix it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you AlbaClan, just trying to help the best I could. Glad you got it working.  Carry on. Good luck!!  :)